# How do I convert audio file to .M4A with 320kbps with NAudio?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

When I try to convert audio file to .m4a with this code

```
using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(input))
    //encoder.Encode(output, reader);
    MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToAac(reader, output, 320000);
```

It always returns a file with bitrate of 192/195kbs. Even this code

```
var bit = MediaFoundationEncoder.GetEncodeBitrates(AudioSubtypes.MFAudioFormat_AAC, 44100, 2);
```

returns bitrates up to 192000.

How do I encode it to 320000kbps instead?

Answer (score 0):

With `MediaFoundationEncoder` you can only encode at the bitrates that media foundation offers. You'll need to find an alternative encoding tool for other bitrates